Need help: can't connect X API to make.com scenario
I've tried to connect my X API to make.com and another service... and both of these have rejected been rejected with an error reading: "something went wrong" --> "You weren’t able to give access to the App. Go back and try logging in again."
why is this happening???
I tried making a different account. I tried unauthorizing and reauthorizing on the X dev platform.
